# how to go back to previous screen ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

In ionic q we will use `$ionichistory.goback()`to go back the previous screen. But in ionic 2 how can we achive that. And i tried this button on click to print the console message . But its not working.

```
<ion-buttons left class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()">
  CANCEL
</ion-buttons>
```

**.js**

```
goback() {
   console.log('Click on button Test Console Log');
}
```

Please help me out. i have two screen . when i go from first screen to next screen. in next screen i have one button called back. When i press that i should be back to first screen. how to so that ?

My full code :

html:

```
<ion-header>
  <!-- use ion-toolbar for a normal toolbar and ion-navbar for navigation -->
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons left class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()">

    CANCEL
    <!-- left aligned content here -->
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>
      LOGIN
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons right class="loginnavbtn" (click)="loginbtntap()">
    SAVE
      <!-- left aligned content here -->
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>


   </ion-content>
```

**my .js :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {


 goback() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
}
loginbtntap() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
}

  constructor(private navCtrl:NavController) {



  }

}
```

**my .scss:**

```
page-login {
ion-header {
  .button-md {
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .toolbar-title {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}

.loginnavbtn {

  color: #116096 !important;
   font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
}
```

Comment: To come this page which method you use this.navCtrl.push(somepage) or this.navCtrl.setRoot(somepage) ?

Answer (score 15):

Check [NavController API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) in the docs.

To go to previous page,inject navcontroller in the constructor and call `pop()`.

```
constructor(private navCtrl:NavController){}

goback() {
   this.navCtrl.pop();
   console.log('Click on button Test Console Log');
}
```

Also check syntax for [button](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#buttons).

```
<ion-buttons >
    <button ion-button left class="loginnavbtn" (click)="goback()">
      Cancel
    </button>
    <!-- left aligned content here -->
    </ion-buttons>
```

Comment: _not working_ meaning? are you getting errors? any logs in console?

Comment: no log messages too. i put my full code in my post.i dont know what i am missing

Comment: i check the problems is in my custom scss code. i wrote that scss code to make the title as centre . but now that making problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716187/ionic-2-back-button-or-any-icon-is-not-showing-only-small-box-icon-is-showing

Comment: You can also just add `navPop` in the button element like this `<button ion-button left class="loginnavbtn" navPop>`

Comment: I would recommend `navPush()` to `navPop()`. Assume we have 3 pages, A, B,C 
 and C can only be called by B(imagine  C is a receipt page). so if I go back to B and do navPop it will go back to the receipt page(C) whereas I would want it to go back to A.

Answer (score 6):

The navigation in Ionic works like:

**1. PUSH Page:**

pageone.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PageTwo }from '../pagetwo/pagetwo';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'pageone.html'
})
export class PageOne {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  push() {
    this.navCtrl.push(PageTwo);
  }
}
```

pageone.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Navigation</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button block (click)="push()">Push New Page</button>
</ion-content>
```

**2.POP Page:**

pagetwo.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'pagetwo.html'
})
export class PageTwo {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  pop() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
}
```

pagetwo.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Page 2</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button color="secondary" block (click)="pop()">Pop This         
Page</button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";

constructor(private location: Location) { }

goBack(){
  this.location.back();
}
```